# Как сравнить две строки в Си без учета регистра, при том что строки могут содержать кириллические символы?

Tags: c

Есть две строки. В этих строках не все символы из набора ASCII. Требуется сравнить эти строки без учета регистра. Есть ли какие-либо стандартные функции для этого?

Comment: а как именно у Вас хранятся строки?

Comment: в char*. Я уже понял, что так не получится, однако я понятия не имею, как хранить двухбайтивые строки.

Comment: то есть, внутри будет UTF-8

Comment: Пожалуй, меня устроит любая кодировка, позволяющая работать как с латинскими символами, так и с кириллицей. Пускай будет UTF-8

Comment: setlocale() и strcasecmp() не работает?

Comment: в целом, для unicode сравнить две строки даже просто на равенство нетривиально (потому что тут есть глифы. code points, проще говоря, букву ё/й можно закодировать двумя способами). Если у Вас линукс - берите либу iconv и вперед.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <wchar.h>

int wcscasecmp( const wchar_t *s1, const wchar_t *s2 );
```

$ man 3 wcscasecmp

Comment: эта функция сравнивает с учетом регистра, а автору вопроса нужно по другому

Comment: Исправил. Надо добавить еще функции работы с UTF-8, но теперь для автора вопроса будет легко разобраться самостоятельно. Примеров в сети масса.